# Single user mode in mac

Tags: macos, text, ctags, mode, cscope

I want to use the mac in single user mode. I want to use ctags and cscope in that mode. Could anyone help me with the setups required for this. Thank you. All i know is how to go to the single user mode so please tell me in a simple and easy to understand method. My mac is version 10.6(snow leopard)

Comment: I can't think of a single good reason why you would want to do this.

Comment: WTF?  Single user mode is for Unix system repair, not for everyday programming.  Do you really just want fullscreen text mode or something, for running cscope?

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a full screen mode you can use (as others have said, you really *don't* want to run in single user mode).

Reboot your Mac and at the login screen, instead of your username type `>console` and leave the password empty. This will then take you to a full screen text mode.

[Note that for this to work you need to be able to type in the username rather than pick it from a list - to enable this go to `System Preferences` => `Accounts` => `Login Options` and select `Name and password`.]

Comment: I realize this is an old comment, but on Mavericks, I only get one screen's worth of lines, and then the last line just keeps resetting. Not very useful, and clear doesn't remove anything from the screen. Any ideas?

Comment: @EricWolf: sorry - I haven't used this method for a few years now - I guess it is such an obscure feature that it doesn't get much love from Apple. It certainly used to work OK in older versions of OS X though. Since we have full screen mode in Terminal now I guess that might be a good alternative, although it's not single user mode of course.